# Switch views from alert view options in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

I want to move to other views created in storyboard through alert view menu buttons displayed in home page. An alert view gives the list of buttons containing different views. 
How can I move to those views.

I am using

```
-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if (buttonIndex == 1){

}
if (buttonIndex ==2) {

}
if(buttonIndex == 3){


}

}
```

Comment: What you have tried? This is very basic question. It seem like you don't know basic of navigation or storyboard. This site is not to learn basic. Ask question when you face problem in your code not to learn how to code. You can learn from here :http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Comment: If you think that I am not understanding your question and your question is not basic than update it with more detail.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get an instance of the storyboard. 
Then you instantiate your Viewcontrollers using the storyboard.
Then you push onto the navigation stack as usual.

```
-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboard_name" bundle:nil];

    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        ViewController1 *vc1 = (ViewController1 *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view1"];
        [self.navigationcontroller pushViewController:vc1];
    }
    if (buttonIndex ==2)
    {
        ViewController2 *vc2 = (ViewController1 *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view2"];
        [self.navigationcontroller pushViewController:vc2];
    }
    if(buttonIndex == 3)
    {
    }
}
```